# FIle dialog gives path that doesn't work with soundplayer

Tags: c#, soundplayer

When I use the file dialog to get a path it gives me the path but it doesn't work with SoundPlayer. The path it returns has the disk letter capitalised which doesn't work with SoundPlayer.

I don't know how to word what I'm searching so I came here

How do I/Can I make it return a path with the disk letter in lower-case?

Comment: You didn't show your code and what kind of sound player are you using

Comment: Well, check `string.ToLower()` otherwise, you can use a combination of `string.SubString()` and `string.ToLower()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `string harddriveletter = yourPath.Substring(0,1)`  to get the hard drive letter then simply `yourPath = yourPath.Replace(harddriveletter,harddriveletter.ToLower())`